# Problem Getting Data from bsrch Using Rblpapi

Tags: r, bloomberg, rblpapi

I can use bsrch in excel to get values given  of "COMDTY:WEATHER" however when I try it using Rblpapi it shows empty data. Also below I have the Excel formulas so you can see how I am trying to get it to work in R below

Observations Basic Query
=BSRCH("comdty:weather","provider=wsi","location=KNYC","model=ACTUALS","cols=15;rows=354")

Observations Specify Parameters
=BSRCH("comdty:weather","provider=wsi","location=KNYC","model=ACTUALS","fields=WIND_SPEED|TEMPERATURE","cols=3;rows=358")

I tried to look for examples online and only found the below, and this code works.

```
#this code works
library(Rblpapi)
blpConnect()

head(bsrch("COMDTY:NGFLOW"), 20)
head(bsrch("COMDTY:VESSEL"), 20)

#this is my code and it doesn't work
head(bsrch("COMDTY:WEATHER"), 20)
```

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: No I have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass in the overrides, requests need to be modified. In this particular request type, the name and value element of values of Overrides array element needs to be modified. In their source code this is not implemented yet, they have a TODO item below.
// TODO - implement limit and other overrides

Hopefully this will be introduced in future versions. Or you can implement yourself.